# array of elements sort like a tree in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, I need to sort this array in accordance with category_level_ids,

```
                Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 8
                            [label] => Position
                            [category_level_ids] => 463,462,461
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 13
                            [label] => Voltage
                            [category_level_ids] => 82,1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 15
                            [label] => Capacity
                            [category_level_ids] => 82,1
                        )                               

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 40
                            [label] => Point Type
                            [category_level_ids] => 242,1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 41
                            [label] => Blade Size
                            [category_level_ids] => 242,1
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 43
                            [label] => No. of Keys
                            [category_level_ids] => 496,494
                        )


                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 77
                            [label] => Condition
                            [category_level_ids] => 494,0
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 84
                            [label] => Fuel
                            [category_level_ids] => 494,0
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [label_id] => 85
                            [label] => Use
                            [category_level_ids] => 82,1
                        )

                )
```

category_level_ids stored with comma separated, In this array category_level_ids :- [82,1] has 3 labels and [242,1] has 2 labels and so on...
I need to display this array in a tree structure,
How can I sort this array like below :-

```
            1 

              82 

                [label_id] => 13  
                [label_id] => 15
                [label_id] => 85

              242

                 [label_id] => 40
                 [label_id] => 41

            0
               494

                  [label_id] => 84
                  [label_id] => 77

                  496

                     [label_id] => 43
```

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I suppose you can't change how the data is stored in first place?

Comment: Can you include the array in a json or var_export format instead?